# Is 1 cup of rice powder equal to 1 cup of uncooked rice?

Tags: rice, flour

Is 1 cup of rice powder equal to 1 cup of uncooked rice? The recipe I am following states, "1 cup rice." I want to use rice flour. Does the density and volume differ?

Comment: It's sort of difficult to answer this if we don't know what you're making and the recipe.

Comment: 1 cup of rice flour is completely different from 1 cup of uncooked rice, they are very different products. I would suggest you specify the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your evident suspicion that 1 cup of whole rice will not be the same amount of rice as 1 cup of rice flour. There would be quite a bit of air in the cup with the whole rice, and not in the cup of rice flour. To get an equivalent amount of "rice-matter", you really need to use weight measurements.

But aha!... Look at this handy-dandy rice unit converter
           http://www.traditionaloven.com/conversions_of_measures/rice_amounts_converter.html

(somebody had too much time on their hands)

Anyway, I tried it out, and according to them, 1 cup(USA) of rice => 185 g => 6.5 oz.

So if you want to get an amount of ground up rice equivalent to 1 cup whole kernels, try 6 and a half oz. ... But, as Catija & GdD point out in comments, the two rice products, even if materially equivalent, aren't going to act the same at all, so be very wary, ready to adjust your amounts empirically, and don't expect your first attempt at this dish to impress critical people.